# HELP ME my dataset xsd content HAS GONE

Tags: xsd, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm working in an erp project using Visual Studio 2008 Sp1, I've a typed dataset it was containg alot of datatable and alot of table adapter the .Designer.cs file was 8 MB, suddenly when i was trying to openit using visual studio designer the following code comes to me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="erpDataSet" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/erpDataSet1.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/erpDataSet1.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/erpDataSet1.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections>
          <Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Settings" AppSettingsPropertyName="erpConnectionString" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="erpConnectionString (Settings)" ParameterPrefix="@" PropertyReference="ApplicationSettings.Sbic.Pro
```

My XSD file content has gone, :( :( :(
I don't understand why, and how can i recover it.
i mad something but i don't know if it is the reason for that or not, My connectionstring was in the settings "app.config" i removed it and add it to the resources of another project that is refernced by the main project.

what can i do, pleaze help me.

Comment: you **do** have a backup of the file, right? In a source control system or something like that....

Comment: well i've but an old one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you were adding code to the ".Designer.cs".  That file is an auto-generated file.   Every time you re-save the XSD file, the designer.cs file will be regenerated.  You should never add content to a designer.cs file.  If you need to add functionality to the dataset, you can extend the dataset by making a "partial" class in a different file using the same namespace that you find in the generated file.